# Getting variable data from a data set in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I need to be able to access each variable's data in my data frame, after the user has selected and uploaded a local csv file.  This code is the part of my Shiny script where I create and modify the csv file read in by the user.  "rv" is the data, which is a reactiveValues dataframe, so it can be modified.
Variable names are chosen by the user through a radio button group (shown here, but defined in the ui part of the script). The other code is in the server portion of the script.

```
             radioButtons('radiovarGroup1',label = h5("Choose a Variable to Analyze:"),
                                  choices = list('TA' = 'TA','PP' = 'PP', 'US' = 'us', 'UD' = 'ud', 'UE' = 'ue',
                                                 'UG' = 'ug', 'UH' = 'uh', 'XR' = 'xr', 'RW' = 'rw', 'PA' = 'pa', 'TB4' = 'tb4',
                                                 'TV2' = 'tv2', 'TV4' = 'tv4', 'TV8' = 'tv8', 'TV20' = 'tv20', 'TV40' = 'tv40', 
                                                 'MV2' = 'mv2', 'MV4' = 'mv4', 'MV8' = 'mv8', 'MV20' = 'mv20', 'MV40' = 'mv40',
                                                 'VB' = 'vb', 'TA40' = 'ta40', 'TA120' = 'ta120', 'SD' = 'sd'),inline = TRUE, selected = NULL),

    var_names = c('TA','PP','US','UD','UE','UG','UH','XR','RW','PA','TB4','TV2','TV4',
                  'TV8','TV20','TV40','MV2','MV4','MV8','MV20','MV40','VB','TA40','TA120','SD')
    
    rv <- reactiveValues(df = NULL)
    
    #This function is responsible for loading in the selected file
    observe({
      req(input$file_selector)
      rv$df <- read.csv(paste0(parseDirPath(c(home = 'C:\\Users\\Ruben\\Desktop\\Test_QC_Program\\FiveMin'), file_dir()),'\\',input$file_selector),skip=1) # Simplified for testing
    })
    
    # This previews the CSV data file
    output$filetable <- renderDataTable({
      rv$df
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$qc_final_cols, {
      if (input$qc_final_cols){
        for (v in 1:length(var_names)){
          ind <- which(colnames(rv$df) == var_names[v])
          rv$df <- rv$df %>% 
            add_column(z = NA,.after = ind)
          colnames(rv$df)[ind+1] <- paste0(var_names[v],'_QC')
          rv$df <- rv$df %>% 
            add_column(y = NA,.after = ind+1)
          colnames(rv$df)[ind+2] <- paste0(var_names[v],'_Final')
        }
      }
    })
    
    output$checked_var <- renderPrint({
      input$radiovarGroup1})
    
    variable_data  <- reactive({get(rv$df[,which(colnames(rv$df) == input$radiovarGroup1)])})
```

Why do I keep getting an "object of type closure is not subsettable' error returned for variable_data?  I can render the rv$df data table just fine, but I can't extract data from it for some reason.

Comment: as `variable_data` is a reactive function, do you call it using `variable_data()`?

Comment: I have solved this issue myself.